# Avoid Word considering start of paragraph as start of sentence

Tags: microsoft-word

I want often want to wrap my notes on a new line but I am getting an uppercase on the first word of the new line or a green line (error). I want to know what is the proper way of doing it.

Example:

> •Revenues
>   Are recorded when they are measurable and available for paying
>   Current period obligations.

On the last line, I want the word Current to be in lower case.

Comment: Is there some particular reason you're pressing ENTER instead of letting the text wrap naturally?

Comment: instead of pressing ENTER you can also press SHIFT+ENTER which will enter a manual line break instead of the paragraph break, and that won't be considered as a new sentence by Word.

Comment: Máté Juhász,  thank you for you for your response. I will put that in my notes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be turned off in the Autocorrect options.

From *Options->Proofing->AutoCorrect Options* untick the box for *Capitalize first letter of sentences*.

[image: Autocorrect dialogue]

This will of course turn off capitalization of all sentences, not just on new lines.

Comment: Chenmunka thank you for your response. Of course, it works and I am happy. Jeff Zeitlin, I am writing my notes and the format is particularly important to me. I am open to other thoughts.